# How to translate values in a column to "yes" and "no" values for a multiple regression in R

Tags: r, variables, linear-regression, multiple-columns

I am doing a multiple linear regression with the following reproducible dataset (this is a small sample of my data):

```
structure(list(age = c(62.84998, 60.33899, 52.74698, 42.38498, 
 79.88495, 93.01599, 62.37097, 86.83899, 85.65594, 42.25897), 
     death = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), sex = c("male", 
     "female", "female", "female", "female", "male", "male", "male", 
     "male", "female"), hospdead = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
     0), slos = c(5, 4, 17, 3, 16, 4, 9, 7, 12, 8), d.time = c(2029, 
     4, 47, 133, 2029, 4, 659, 142, 63, 370), dzgroup = c("Lung Cancer", 
     "Cirrhosis", "Cirrhosis", "Lung Cancer", "ARF/MOSF w/Sepsis", 
     "Coma", "CHF", "CHF", "Lung Cancer", "Colon Cancer"), dzclass = c("Cancer", 
     "COPD/CHF/Cirrhosis", "COPD/CHF/Cirrhosis", "Cancer", "ARF/MOSF", 
     "Coma", "COPD/CHF/Cirrhosis", "COPD/CHF/Cirrhosis", "Cancer", 
     "Cancer"), num.co = c(0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 0), edu = c(11, 
     12, 12, 11, NA, 14, 14, NA, 12, 11), income = c("$11-$25k", 
     "$11-$25k", "under $11k", "under $11k", NA, NA, "$25-$50k", 
     NA, NA, "$25-$50k"), scoma = c(0, 44, 0, 0, 26, 55, 0, 26, 
     26, 0), charges = c(9715, 34496, 41094, 3075, 50127, 6884, 
     30460, 30460, NA, 9914), totcst = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
     NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
     NA_real_), totmcst = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
     NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
     ), avtisst = c(7, 29, 13, 7, 18.666656, 5, 8, 6.5, 8.5, 8
     ), race = c("other", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
     "white", "white", "white", "black", "hispanic"), sps = c(33.8984375, 
     52.6953125, 20.5, 20.0976562, 23.5, 19.3984375, 17.296875, 
     21.5976562, 15.8984375, 2.2998047), aps = c(20, 74, 45, 19, 
     30, 27, 46, 53, 17, 9), surv2m = c(0.262939453, 0.0009999275, 
     0.790893555, 0.698974609, 0.634887695, 0.284973145, 0.892944336, 
     0.670898438, 0.570922852, 0.952880859), surv6m = c(0.0369949341, 
     0, 0.664916992, 0.411987305, 0.532958984, 0.214996338, 0.820922852, 
     0.498962402, 0.24899292, 0.887939453), hday = c(1, 3, 4, 
     1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), diabetes = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
     0, 0), dementia = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), ca = c("metastatic", 
     "no", "no", "metastatic", "no", "no", "no", "no", "metastatic", 
     "metastatic"), prg2m = c(0.5, 0, 0.75, 0.899999619, 0.899999619, 
     0, NA, 0.799999714, 0.049999982, NA), prg6m = c(0.25, 0, 
     0.5, 0.5, 0.8999996, 0, 0.6999998, 0.3999999, 0.0001249999, 
     NA), dnr = c("no dnr", NA, "no dnr", "no dnr", "no dnr", 
     "no dnr", "no dnr", "no dnr", "dnr after sadm", "no dnr"), 
     dnrday = c(5, NA, 17, 3, 16, 4, 9, 7, 2, 8), meanbp = c(97, 
     43, 70, 75, 59, 110, 78, 72, 97, 84), wblc = c(6, 17.0976562, 
     8.5, 9.09960938, 13.5, 10.3984375, 11.6992188, 13.5996094, 
     9.69921875, 11.2988281), hrt = c(69, 112, 88, 88, 112, 101, 
     120, 100, 56, 94), resp = c(22, 34, 28, 32, 20, 44, 28, 26, 
     20, 20), temp = c(36, 34.59375, 37.39844, 35, 37.89844, 38.39844, 
     37.39844, 37.59375, 36.59375, 38.19531), pafi = c(388, 98, 
     231.65625, NA, 173.3125, 266.625, 309.5, 404.75, 357.125, 
     NA), alb = c(1.7998047, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.7998047, NA, 
     NA, 4.6992188), bili = c(0.19998169, NA, 2.19970703, NA, 
     NA, NA, 0.39996338, NA, 0.39996338, 0.19998169), crea = c(1.19995117, 
     5.5, 2, 0.79992676, 0.79992676, 0.69995117, 1.59985352, 2, 
     1, 0.79992676), sod = c(141, 132, 134, 139, 143, 140, 132, 
     139, 143, 139), ph = c(7.459961, 7.25, 7.459961, NA, 7.509766, 
     7.65918, 7.479492, 7.509766, 7.449219, NA), glucose = c(NA_real_, 
     NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
     NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), bun = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
     NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
     NA_real_, NA_real_), urine = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
     NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
     NA_real_), adlp = c(7, NA, 1, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0), adls = c(7, 
     1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 7, NA), sfdm2 = c(NA, "<2 mo. follow-up", 
     "<2 mo. follow-up", "no(M2 and SIP pres)", "no(M2 and SIP pres)", 
     "<2 mo. follow-up", "no(M2 and SIP pres)", NA, NA, NA), adlsc = c(7, 
     1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 7, 0.4947999)), row.names = c(NA, 10L
 ), class = "data.frame")
```

I have my formula for the regression here.

```
SB_xlsx13 = SB_xlsx13[!is.na(SB_xlsx13$dnrday), ]
SB_xlsx13 = SB_xlsx13[!is.na(SB_xlsx13$sps), ]
MLR_2 = lm(SB_xlsx13$hospdead ~ SB_xlsx13$dzclass_f + SB_xlsx13$age + SB_xlsx13$sex + SB_xlsx13$num.co + SB_xlsx13$sps)
summary(MLR_2)
## 
## Call:
## lm(formula = SB_xlsx13$hospdead ~ SB_xlsx13$dzclass_f + SB_xlsx13$age + 
##     SB_xlsx13$sex + SB_xlsx13$num.co + SB_xlsx13$sps)
## 
## Residuals:
##      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
## -1.26132 -0.25758 -0.08914  0.15412  1.14048 
## 
## Coefficients:
##                                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
## (Intercept)                           -0.3519553  0.0224017 -15.711  < 2e-16
## SB_xlsx13$dzclass_fCancer             -0.0870012  0.0123327  -7.055 1.86e-12
## SB_xlsx13$dzclass_fComa                0.2907825  0.0164644  17.661  < 2e-16
## SB_xlsx13$dzclass_fCOPD/CHF/Cirrhosis -0.1378731  0.0104787 -13.157  < 2e-16
## SB_xlsx13$age                          0.0027082  0.0002555  10.598  < 2e-16
## SB_xlsx13$sexmale                      0.0022789  0.0079126   0.288    0.773
## SB_xlsx13$num.co                       0.0028155  0.0032577   0.864    0.387
## SB_xlsx13$sps                          0.0184986  0.0004393  42.105  < 2e-16
##                                          
## (Intercept)                           ***
## SB_xlsx13$dzclass_fCancer             ***
## SB_xlsx13$dzclass_fComa               ***
## SB_xlsx13$dzclass_fCOPD/CHF/Cirrhosis ***
## SB_xlsx13$age                         ***
## SB_xlsx13$sexmale                        
## SB_xlsx13$num.co                         
## SB_xlsx13$sps                         ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Residual standard error: 0.3724 on 9067 degrees of freedom
## Multiple R-squared:  0.2772, Adjusted R-squared:  0.2767 
## F-statistic: 496.8 on 7 and 9067 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

The regression comes out just fine; however, I want to add one more variable(s), which is dnr status at day three. If the value is 3 or less, there is a DNR and if the value is over 3, there is not a DNR. I previously subsetted these values for a previous task using this code:

```
YesDNR <- subset(SB_xlsx12, dnrday <= 3, na.rm=TRUE)
NoDNR <- subset(SB_xlsx12, dnrday > 3, na.rm=TRUE)
```

This worked fine, but I can't really use these subsets in my regression model. I would assume to make the model work, I would need to translate every value of 3 or less (<=) in the "dnrday" column to "yes" and every value over 3 (>) to "no". Am I correct on this thinking, and if so, how would I accomplish changing those values.

Comment: you can do that in the formula `lm(mpg ~ disp + hp + I(wt <= 3), mtcars)`

Comment: I notice you have a binary outcome variable here. If you are trying to model the probability of in-hospital death, you should be using logistic regression, not linear regression. It's almost as easy to do in R as linear regression. This is not just some statistical technicality - it is absolutely fundamental. If you use linear regression, you will end up with predicted probabilities of less than 0 and greater than 1 for some cases, which is completely nonsensical.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thank you for pointing that out! I looked back at some notes and yeah, logistic makes a lot more sense over doing linear regression. I had a previous project I was working on related to hospital charges rather than in-hospital death, so I just transferred the code over without thinking about the differences between charges (any possible numbers) and the "yes" "no" nature of in-hospital death. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a new column - see two options below.

(NB in `lm()` you don't have to specify `SB_xlsx13$` each time you add a covariate if you list it as the `data =`  argument once! This will make your output easier to read.)

**Tidyverse approach**: `mutate` and `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)
SB_xlsx13 <- SB_xlsx13 %>%
  mutate(dnr_d3 = case_when(dnrday <= 3 ~ "yes",
                            dnrday > 3 ~ "no",
                            TRUE ~ NA_character_))

MLR_3 <- lm(hospdead ~ dzclass + age + sex + num.co + sps + dnr_d3,
            data = SB_xlsx13)
```

**Base R approach**:

```
SB_xlsx13$dnr_d3[SB_xlsx13$dnrday <= 3] <- "yes"
SB_xlsx13$dnr_d3[SB_xlsx13$dnrday > 3] <- "no"
MLR_4 <- lm(hospdead ~ dzclass + age + sex + num.co + sps + dnr_d3,
            data = SB_xlsx13)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may simply use the AsIs function `I()` in the formula. Also use `factor` to easily factorize variables.

```
lm(hospdead ~ factor(dzclass) + I(dnrday <= 3) + age + sex + num.co + sps, 
   SB_xlsx13)
```

This might look a bit unclean but it's nice for playing around with the data. Once you are happy with something you may easily change it in the data using `transform`. For instance, the DNR variable can be created boolean just using `dnrday <= 3`.

```
SB_xlsx13 <- transform(SB_xlsx13,
                       dzclass_f=as.factor(dzclass),
                       dnrday_3=dnrday <= 3)
```